# SQL Insert com quebra de linha

Tags: firebird, sql-insert

Com esse comando **SQL** insiro alguns dados na tabela, o problema é, no sistema o campo “ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.OBSERVACAO” está com *quebra de linhas* e na hora de salvar via **SQL** a quebra de linha é perdida.

Teria como fazer esse `SQL insert` sem perder a quebra de linha? Como seria?

```
INSERT INTO ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS
    (ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.CODIGO_ANDAMENTO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.DESCRICAO_ANDAMENTO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.OBSERVACAO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.NUMERO_PROCESSO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.INSTANCIA,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.ACESSO_PUBLICO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.EMAIL_ENVIADO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.CODIGO_PUBLICACAO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.CODIGO_AUDIENCIA,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.CODIGO_AGENDAMENTO,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.DATA,
     ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS.HORA)
VALUES
    (CODIGO_ANDAMENTO,
     DESCRICAO_ANDAMENTO,
     OBSERVACAO,
     NUMERO_PROCESSO,
     NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX,
     INSTANCIA,
     ACESSO_PUBLICO,
     EMAIL_ENVIADO,
     CODIGO_PUBLICACAO,
     CODIGO_AUDIENCIA,
     CODIGO_AGENDAMENTO,
     DATA,
     HORA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja bem, dando uma olhada na Documentação do **Firebird** e vendo a resposta de @Pedro Cardoso

> ```
> --CHAR(13) - Quebra de Linha
> --CHAR(10) - Mudança de Linha
>
> DECLARE @texto NVARCHAR(100)
> SET @texto = 'Esta e a linha numero um.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Esta e a linha numero dois.'
> SELECT @texto
> ```

O Correspondente ao firebird do

- `CHAR(13)` é o `ASCII_CHAR(13)`
- `CHAR(10)` é o `ASCII_CHAR(10)`
  Com isso, basta você montar sua SQL Query como melhor lhe atenda.

**Obs** a separação do Comando e da String no Firebird deve ser pelo  `||` e não com `+`

Comment: Vou tentar aqui e para ver se funciona...

Answer (score 0):

E SQL 2016 ?

Se sim tens de checkar nas opções do SSMS -> Query Results -> Results to grid -> Reain CR/LF.

Caso não seja verifica se isto te ajuda:

```
--CHAR(13) - Quebra de Linha
--CHAR(10) - Mudança de Linha

DECLARE @texto NVARCHAR(100)
SET @texto = 'Esta e a linha numero um.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Esta e a linha numero dois.'
SELECT @texto
```

Comment: Explica melhor pois não sou muito bom com sql e não entendo direito '(¬¬)

Comment: Tens de substituir o "Enter" por CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) na variavel antes de fazeres o insert.

Comment: @EduardoMendonçadaSilva #13 e #10 são os códigos [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) para "quebrar linha" o Pedro está sugerindo para você injetar um código de quebra de linha no meio do texto

Comment: Eu to utilizando Delphi 10.2 e Firebird como seria isso para o firebird?

Comment: Estamos a falar de SQL puro, nao conheço essas linguagens.

Comment: Você fez a pergunta pra SQL @EduardoMendonçadaSilva...

Comment: `sql`           - Porque é um comando Sql     `sql-insert` - Porque se trata de Insert      `firebird`     - Porque é no Banco de dados Firebird.
é só da uma olhada nas tag's